How can I add a class to a list item?
I have created an item list inside a foreach loop like
$items[] = [
  '#markup' => 'some html text'
]

then pass it to
themed_list = [
 '#theme' => 'item_list',
 '#items' => $items,  
 '#attributes' => ['class' => ['my-list-class']],
];

this works fine with the Drupal's standard item_list.html.twig
{% if context.list_style %}
    {%- set wrapper_attributes = wrapper_attributes.addClass('item-list--' ~ context.list_style) %}
    {%- set attributes = attributes.addClass('item-list__' ~ context.list_style) %}
{% endif %}
{% if items or empty -%}
    <div{{wrapper_attributes.addClass('item-list')}}>
        {%- if title is not empty -%}
            <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- if items -%}
            <{{list_type}}{{attributes.addClass('list-group')}}>
                {%- for item in items -%}
                    <li{{item.attributes.addClass('list-group-item')}}>{{ item.value }}</li>
                {%- endfor -%}
            </{{list_type}}>
        {%- else -%}
            {{- empty -}

